# I am trying to run multiple test cases one by one on Appium through testNG on single device

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, appium

My first test case runs successfully, but on second test case. I get the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. Details: Problem getting session data for driver type
>
> AndroidDriver; does it implement 'get driverData'? (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
>
> Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'abhishek-Aspire-E1-572', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-56-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
>
> Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

Sharing my capabilities, given below:-

```
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> d = null;
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
if(remoteExecution.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
if (browser.equals("samsung")) {
        System.out.println(browser);
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "4d00b83ed4f7426f");  
        //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 30);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.1");
        cap.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability("waitForAppScript", Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability("noReset",Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.rentitbae");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.rentitbae.MainActivity");


    } else if (browser.equals("micromax")) {
        System.out.println(browser);
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "0123456789ABCDEF");  
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4.2");
        cap.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability("waitForAppScript", Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.rentitbae");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.rentitbae.MainActivity");

    } else if (browser.equals("jelly beans")) {
        System.out.println(browser);
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "192.168.56.101:5555");  
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.2.2");
        cap.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability("waitForAppScript", Boolean.TRUE);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.rentitbae");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.rentitbae.MainActivity");

    }
}

    URL url = new URL(gridHubRemoteUrl);
    System.out.println(cap.getBrowserName());
    d = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);
return d;
}
```

Sharing Testng.xml suite :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suite name="Suite">
        <test name="Tests">
            <classes>
                <class name="android_rib.VerifyLoginFBTest"/>
                <class name="android_rib.VerifyLoginGmailTest"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

config.property file :-

```
browser=samsung
#browser=micromax
browser=jelly beans

timeoutInSec=10
remoteExecution=true
gridEnabled=false
gridHubRemoteUrl=http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
```

Comment: Could you share your Test case flow? It looks like you're trying to create a new AndroidDriver session at Test Case 2 while the session from Test Case 1 still exists.

Comment: provide more info. capabilities, e.t.c....

Comment: I have two test cases (VerifyLoginFBTest and VerifyLoginGmailTest) so when I am running both test cases individually they execute well and successfully but I want to run my test-cases continuously one by one, and what exactly i am doing, running my test cases as testng suite. My first test "VerifyLoginFBTest" successfully execute and than application close after that on second test case "VerifyLoginGmailTest" I am getting an error that **org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. Details: Problem getting session data for driver type**